# Code doesn't print last k length combination of n elements?

Tags: c++, while-loop, combinations

I wrote code that prints `classLength` length combinations out of `length` elements. It works fine but I don't understand why.

**My Questions:**

1. When the

   ```
   while(index[0] != length - classLength)
   ```

   loop finishes **the program doesn't print the last combination so I have to print it after the `while` loop. Why is that?**
2. I tried changing the condition in the above mentioned `while` loop.

   Instead `length-classLength` I wrote `lenght-classLength+1`

   **When running the program this resulted in an infinite loop. Why did this happen?**
3. Note the commented part of the

   ```
   while(index[position] == maxIndex /*&& position >= 0*/)
   ```

   `while` loop condition and commented `if` statement

   ```
   /*if(position>=0)*/ index[position]++;
   ```

   **Program will run fine when those parts of code are uncommented and when they are commented.** I originally wrote the code with those conditions so the program doesn't access an array with an improper index. But this works just fine without those security checks. **Why are indices always in range and errors don't occur?**

**C++ code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

    /**Print all combinations of k-th class of n elements**/

int main() {
    const int maxN = 100;
    int length = 0, classLength = 0;
    cout << "Input number of elements and class number: " << endl;
    cin >> length >> classLength;

    int array[maxN];
    cout << "Input elements: " << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        cin >> array[i];

    //first combination has indices 0, 1, ... , k-1
    int index[maxN];
    for(int i = 0; i < classLength; i++)
        index[i] = i;

    int ordNum = 1;
    ofstream out("output.txt");
    //length of class is classLength, last combination's last element's index is n-1
    //last combination's last element's index is n-1-k
    while(index[0] != length - classLength) {
        //print current combination
        out << ordNum++ << ")\t";
        for(int i = 0; i < classLength; i++)
            out << array[index[i]] << " ";
        out << endl;

        int position = classLength-1, maxIndex = length-1;
        //if index at current position is its max
        // value then we have to carry digit
        while(index[position] == maxIndex /*&& position >= 0*/) {
            index[position] = -1;
            position--, maxIndex--;
        }

        //when loop stops position is at index that
        //should be added the carried 1
        /*if(position>=0)*/
        index[position]++;

        //if a carry accured indices must be arranged so that
        //array index[] is non-decreasing
        for(int i = 1; i < classLength; i++)
            if(index[i] <= index[i-1])
                index[i] = index[i-1]+1;
    }

    out << ordNum++ << ")\t";
    for(int i = 0; i < classLength; i++)
        out << array[index[i]] << " ";
    out << endl;

    out.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with minimal being the keyword here. One question per question please, break the above into multiple posts if needed. Please take [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Resolving your first issue will help you to understand the second question. The second question will help you to understand the others. You sould take a paper and trace what the both code do.